# How to link to portfolio page with a specific filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm playing with a portfolio section in a page that looks like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var selectedClass = "";
  $(".fil-cat").click(function() {
    selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel");
    $("#portfolio").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
    $("#portfolio div").not("." + selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("." + selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
      $("#portfolio").fadeTo(300, 1);
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 900px;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
}

#portfolio {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1rem;
  -moz-column-gap: 1rem;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  -webkit-column-width: 33.33333333333333%;
  -moz-column-width: 33.33333333333333%;
  column-width: 33.33333333333333%;
}

.tile {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease;
  transition: all 350ms ease;
}

.tile:hover {}

.scale-anm {
  transform: scale(1);
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc dotted;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: lato;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

p:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
}

.tile img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.btn {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #555;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: var(--darken-2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--darken-3);
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/basscss@8.0.0/css/basscss.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="toolbar mb2 mt2">
  <button class="btn fil-cat" href="" data-rel="all">All</button>
  <button class="btn fil-cat" data-rel="web">Websites</button>
  <button class="btn fil-cat" data-rel="flyers">Flyers</button>
  <button class="btn fil-cat" data-rel="bcards">Business Cards</button>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

From a different page I have a button with a link to the portfolio section. But what I'd like to have is a button (in a different page) that goes to the portfolio, already filtering to a certain element. For example, from another page I want to take the user straight to the "Flyers" elements, so the don't have to filter anything. Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

**Edited**

After trying the solution for answer marked as right I noticed that it was working for one particular case, the one as `working` this is what I added, whenever I change my link too `/our-work#other-case` the page is presented but not filtered accordingly

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    switch(hash){
        case 'case-one':
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
                $('#case-one').click();
        case 'working':
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
                $('#working').click();
        case 'case-two':
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
                $('#case-two').click();
        case 'case-three':
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
                $('#case-three').click();
        case 'case-four':
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
                $('#case-four').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one not elegant but working method using only JS and Html

specify an anchor tag in the link such as `yourwebsite.com/portfolio#Flyers`

then

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    switch(hash){
        case 'Flyers':
            $('#FlyersButtonId').click();
        ///..... case for other filters
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is this not elegant?

Comment: Just assuming there's a better way than having a hash in your URL. I know this works though!

Comment: Hi again, I noticed that using this solution for some reason only works for only one case `working`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this and the proper way to do it would be to [manipulate the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History_API) as you use your filter, using the [`replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) method.

**Note:** If you want the user to be able to go through different filter states as they click the back browser button, you want to use `pushState()` instead of `replaceState()` but, generally speaking, adding filter states as separate entries in browser history is considered bad practice because it annoys users, when they want to go back to the previous page/website.

The state object is a bit more complex than this but, in essence, you're just creating/replacing some back/forward points in the history of the browser each time the filter is used. The third parameter is the most important, because it actually changes the url of the browser, meaning that your user, at any time, can copy/paste the current address and share it with someone else and they will both see the same content.

So, modify your filtering javascript and, when you apply a filter also:

```
window.history.pushState({filcat:"whatever"}, "Title", "#whatever");
```

...where `whatever` is your applied filter and "Title" is the title you want your page to have when in that state. I also used `filcat` as the property name of the `state` object, according to your existing code.

Of course, you will also need a simple script that will read the current url on page load and adjust the contents accordingly.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  if (window.location.hash) {
    // do something here. 
    // For example, if window.location.hash (i.e.: "#whatever") and 
    // the id of your buttons match, you might even do:

    $(window.location.hash).trigger('click')
  }
})
```

I hope I've set you in the right direction.